# iAd in iphone application "'ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50' undeclared (first use in this function)"

Tags: iphone, ios4, iad

I am using iAd in my iphone 4.0 application but after adding the ADBannerView on view and when i try to set the ADBannerView properties using below code :-

```
adViewTemp.requiredContentSizes= [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
```

I get the below error message:-

> error:
>   'ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50'
>   undeclared (first use in this
>   function)

and i also check the sample provided by apple "iAdSuite" i get the same error in this sample.
so can any one suggest how i solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have imported the iAds Franework and included the import statement.

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

Comment: Ya i already have added this header. i also try the run sample provided by apple but the same error occur. so plz suggest any other problem... ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not just the header, add the Framework. In Frameworks on the left, cmd-click, choose Add Existing Frameworks, select the iAd framework.